# Can I get a return value of some kind from a ssh command?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh

I'm running the following command in a while loop, going through a list of machines:

```
ssh -n -o ConnectTimeout=10 hostname 'smbios-sys-info' >> MACHINEINFO
```

Works great.  Except when I run into a connection that fails or times out, it outputs the timeout error message into MACHINEINFO.  I instead want it to silently fail without muddling MACHINEINFO, but instead write the hostname of the failed connection into another file like FAILEDMACHINES.

I assume to do something like this I'd need to get a return value from ssh to determine whether or not the connection and smbios-sys-info command ran successfully, and if not, output to FAILEDMACHINES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running the command, `$?` will give you the result code.

If the ssh succeeds, $? will be the result code of the remote command, otherwise, it will return 255.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb for asking this.  So simple.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't feel dumb for asking - it's a reasonable question.